# Base WHERE statement with many OR statements

Tags: sql, ms-access

(insert typical I'm a noob comment and a million apologies for asking a noob question)

I'm trying to simplify a query where I'm trimming a set of data. I've created a WHERE statement from all the other OR statements to be based off of. The issue I'm having now is not repeating the base WHERE statement for each OR condition.

**What I'm having to do:**

```
WHERE ((base conditions) AND X) OR 
((base conditions) AND Y) OR
ETC.....
```

**What I want to do**

```
WHERE ((base conditions) OR X OR Y)
```

I'm thinking I can set up the base conditions and then query the base condition with OR statements but I don't know if that's what I'm suppose to do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do that.  You just need parentheses:

```
WHERE (base conditions) AND
      (X OR Y OR Z . . .)
```